# Literature for noncommutative birational invariants

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, birational-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, division-algebras

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of zero characteristic. All fields under discussion are fields over $k$, and all division rings are division algebras over $k$.

There is rich theory of birational invariants of fields $F / k$. By a birational invariant of a field $F/k$ I mean of course any invariant that is the same for two fields when they are isomorphic.
Such invariants are important when we want to show that two fields $F/k$ and $L/k$ are not isomorphic, and the most basic invariant is the transcendence degree (denoted here by $\operatorname{trdeg}_k$).

One of the main application of birational invariants of fields is, of course, the problem of birational classification of projective varieties in algebraic geometry (since classifying varieties up to birational equivalence is the same thing as to classify the isomorphisms classes of the function fields). This is a huge area of research - for a reference, we have the nice book by Kollár and Mori, 'Birational geometry of algebraic varieties', and the many papers it mentions.

The first attempt to introduce an analogue of transcendence degree for division algebras is due to Gelfand and Kirillov in their seminal paper of 1966 (where $\operatorname{GK}$-dimension was also introduced). This is the so called Gelfand-Kirillov transcendence degree (denoted $\operatorname{GKtrdeg}_k$).

It was originally introduced for studying of the rings of fractions of the Weyl algebras (usually called 'Weyl fields'), and enveloping algebras (in relation to Gelfand-Kirillov Conjecture), and as expected it coincides with $\operatorname{trdeg}_k$ when the division algebra is a field. However there are some issues with $\operatorname{GKtrdeg}_k$: it is very difficult to compute in practice, and lacks some desirable properties of a transcendence degree. For instance: (1) if $D_1 \subset D_2$ are two division algebras, it is true that $\operatorname{GKtrdeg}_k(D_1) \leq \operatorname{GKtrdeg}_k (D_2)$? (2) if $[D_2: D_1]$ is finite, do we have $\operatorname{GKtrdeg}_k(D_2)=\operatorname{GKtrdeg}_k(D_1)$? These are still open problems.

In the 1980's we have the introduction of quantum groups, and in the 90's people realized that many of them are Ore domains which have interesting rings of fractions (which are certain quantum analogues of the Weyl fields). We also have in the 90's the development of noncommutative projective geometry and the emergence of the problem of classifying noncommutative surfaces up to birational equivalence.

So there was a increasing interest in noncommutative notions of transcendence degrees. In 1998 J. J. Zhang introduced the lower transcendence degree (denoted $\operatorname{LD}_k$). It has many nice theoretical properties (for instance it has answer 'yes' for questions (1) and (2) above), and conjecturally is equal to the Gelfand-Kirillov transcendence degree in the case of division algebras.

However, again $\operatorname{LD}_k$ is hard to compute in general. In 2006, Yekutieli and J. J. Zhang introduced the homological transcendence degree (denoted $\operatorname{Htrdeg}_k$). It also has good theoretical properties and for algebras with good homological properties, such as Artin-Schelter regular algebras, it is not hard to compute. But I note that $\operatorname{Htrdeg}_k \neq \operatorname{GKtrdeg}_k$ for division algebras (in case this turns out to be important).

As interesting as these notions of noncommutative transcendence degrees are, they fail to show that some "obviously" non-isomorphic division algebras are, indeed, non-isomorphic. For instance, let $q$ be a non-root of unity and let $k_q(x,y)$ denote the ring of fractions of the quantum plane, and let $W_1(k)$ denote the first Weyl field. All that, for instance, $\operatorname{LD}_k$ says is that $\operatorname{LD}_k(k_q(x,u))=\operatorname{LD}_k(W_1(k))=2$.

(In fact, in 1994 Alev and Dumas introduced certain invariants of division algebras that detect relations of the form $yx=qxy$ and of the form $xy=yx+1$, showing that, as expected, the rings of fractions appearing from quantum groups are not isomorphic to Weyl fields).

As this simple example shows, there should be more subtle noncommutative birational invariants for division algebras showing when they are not isomorphic.

As another example, we may consider M. Artin's famous conjecture about what types of division algebras can appear as 'function fields' of noncommutative projective surfaces. In Artin's conjecture, the possibilities are:

i) division algebras which are finite over their centers, which are function fields of transcendence degree 2.

ii) $k_q(x,y)$, where $q \in k$ is not a root of unity.

iii) The Sklyanin division ring $S(E, \sigma)$, which is the zero degree part of the graded division ring of the Sklyanin algebra $A(E, \sigma)$. Here $E$ denotes an elliptic curve and $\sigma$ denotes translation by a point of infinite order.

iv) $W_1(k)$

v) the field of fractions of the Ore extension $k(E)[t,\sigma]$ ($E$ and $\sigma$ as above)

vi) $Q(D(C))$, the ring of fractions of the ring of differential operators $D(C)$ on a curve $C$ with positive genus.

Now, of course one must show that the division algebras appearing in i)-vi) are not isomorphic. This can be shown using the notion of prime divisor (for which I refer Artin's original paper).

So far, so good, but even in this case I don't know a complete solution to the isomorphism problem of the division algebras of the type appearing in i).

After this rather long introduction, I come to my question. I'm interested in references, be they lecture notes, research papers, surveys, etc, for what is currently known about noncommutative birational invariants (pherhaps I should be precise on what I mean: a birational invariant of division algebras is one which coincides when two division algebras are isomorphic; and I'm interested in the case where they are efficient in showing that relevant division algebras are *not* isomorphic).

In am no specialist in noncommutative geometry, but I imagine that refined notions of noncommutative birational invariants should be very useful in the theory.

Such notions of birational invariants certainly are desirable in certain parts of Lie theory. A very important problem about enveloping algebras of algebraic Lie algebras $\mathfrak{g}$ is to determine when the ring of frations of $U(\mathfrak{g})$ is a Weyl field. Another important problem is to determine when the ring of fractions of $\mathcal{D}(X)^G$, the invariant subring of the algebra of differential operators on an affine variety $X$, is a Weyl field. I do not expect there should be a birational invariant that complently settle these questions, as both problems are very hard problems; but pherhaps a suitable noncommutative birational invariant could make such problems easier in some cases.